# Test framework for Greasemonkey scripts

Tags: javascript, testing, greasemonkey

I need a framework for testing my greasemonkey scripts.  [UxU claims to provide this](http://www.clear-code.com/software/uxu/index.html.en) but I don't read Japanese, so I can't really follow the documentation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google translate does a good job cleaning up the non-English version of those pages](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http://www.clear-code.com/software/uxu/greasemonkey.html&sl=ja&tl=en&hl=&ie=UTF-8).

And, if you download the code (uxu-0.9.0.xpi), it is in English.

Also, for automated test, [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) should work on/with GM-modified pages (but I haven't needed to try it myself).